# HTTP heartbeat to avoid connection drop for long running http calls

Tags: angular, http, spring-boot, heroku, timeout

I have an app deployed on Heroku PaaS.

They have a timeout policy like this (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout):

30 seconds, extending by 55 seconds each time a byte is sent or received in the connection.

I have http endpoints that can take a while (upload file, take some time to ingest it, and return 200 ok).
If the processing takes more than 30 seconds, to connection is dropped by Heroku router, and the whole thing is aborted.

There are plain HTTP/JSON  API endpoints.
Client is Angular 6+, server is Spring Boot 2+ (Spring MVC, no reactive stuff).

I know I could make the process asynchronous, no need to point me in that direction.

The question is: **is there a way to keep sending stuff in the connection while the data are being processed, either from the browser or from the server side ?**

Some kind of keepalive noise, like what can be done in a SSH connection.

Something I could add in the Angular app as an interceptor would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

in our app we can send plain request to the api so the login would stay alive. maybe similar you can do for your app?

```js
return this.http
      .get('login_url')
      .pipe(
        map(() => {
          console.log('Heartbeat OK.');
          localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', 'true');
          return '1';
        }),
        timeout(this.appConfigService.getConfig().heartbeatTimeout),
        catchError(() => {
          console.log('Heartbeat Error');
          localStorage.setItem('isAuthenticated', 'false');
          return '0';
        }),
        retry(),
        delay(this.appConfigService.getConfig().heartbeatDelay),
        repeat()
      );
```